# User should input an integer by scanner class getting an input and check in if condition

Tags: java, input

Requirements:

1. Get a input number from user.
2. Validate the whether the given input is number or not.
3. If it a number, then check Fibonacci series and display a message for the same.
4. If the input is not number, then display, "please enter a number" and again ask for the input.
5. User should give 'Q' to exit
6. If a input is given. Do the above process and ask for the next input, till they hit 'Q'.

I have made an logic but unable to check in if condition

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    boolean quit = false;
    BufferedReader re = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number :");
    int n;
    while (!quit) {
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            n = sc.nextInt();
            while (n <= 0) {
                System.out.println("*****Fibonacci Series*****");
                int f1, f2 = 0, f3 = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

                    f1 = f2;
                    f2 = f3;
                    f3 = f1 + f2;
                    System.out.print(" " + f3 + " ");
                }
            }
            quit = false;
        } else if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("That's not a number!");
            sc.next();
            quit = false;

        } else(sc.hasNextInt().equals("q")) {
            quit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

in if condition it throws error has .class expected

Comment: `if (sc.nextInt().equals(int))`: what exactly do you want to achieve with this incorrect instruction? Have you read the javadoc of `Scanner.nextInt()` to understand what it does, and what happens if the next token is not an int?

Comment: Sorry I will post my full code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if condition you are looking for is `if (sc.hasNextInt())`

After that you can call `sc.nextInt();`

The whole check could look like this:

```
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            //do something with num
        }
        else if (sc.hasNext() && ("q".equals(sc.next())) ) {
                //do something
        }
```

For details on `Scanner` please read [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: Thank you and If i need to check whether it is string or not in else condition should I use (!sc.hasNextInt()) also in if else (sc.hasNextInt().equals("q"))

Comment: **sc.hasNextInt().equals("q"))** is that correct in else loop

Comment: You should read Javadoc of java.lang.Scanner. `hasNextInt` returns a boolean on which you cannot call `equals` (or any other method).